# Can you call donations "volunteer work"

Tags: volunteering

I have been doing some volunteering here and there but I want to know if I can list non-currency donations as volunteering.
I make hand-made hats for those who have cancer and donate my hair. I send them to non-profit organization.
I want to know if I list this as volunteering.Thanks for taking your time to read this

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Workplace question...  Or if it is, you need to ask your company whether they consider it volunteering.

Comment: Yes, I think you can list this as volunteering. Why not ?

Comment: Where are you thinking of listing this? You can put anything you like on your CV, personal website, etc. (the real question is then whether it's is worth the space, and how to present it) but if this is for some company-specific thing, for example a CSR-related day off, that's up to them.

Comment: You need to provide context. Do you want to list non-business related activities in a CV? Do you intend to claim a tax refund (which often is possible with monetary donations but probably not with volunteer work)?

Comment: Both donation and volunteering are subsets charity contributions. But they are different things under US tax law (I don't know about elsewhere), and under most company policies. The question doesn't give context, so we can't guess which definition is being applied.

Comment: The potential employers will surely appreciate what you did (making hats for charity, etc...) So, you can simply write "**I make hand-made hats for those who have cancer and donate my hair. I send them to non-profit organization**" on your resume. This will have a very nice and positive impression to the potential employers. Don't worry about whether this meets the definition of **volunteering** or not.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I really can't tell whether or not you're being sarcastic here... Assuming this is serious, some employers might appreciate it, others won't care or will think of it as wasting their time. I'd at least try and research whether the potential employer values charity work and I'd put it somewhere at the bottom after everything more important if at all

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.

Now - granted, you are still doing some form of volunteer work (and that's a good thing) - but you making items to donate in your free time is not the same as working a shift volunteering.

Put it this way - recently I volunteered at our local School Gala and my Wife did some baking for the bake sale.

One was done in the comfort of our own home on our own terms, the other someone had to go to a place, at a set time, and work as directed.

That's the key difference.

Comment: So you don't respect the physical labour that goes into producing something like cakes or knitting hats? imho poor, very poor.

Comment: @SolarMike Considering where we are, I would assume "volunteering" is meant in the context or workplace and/or applications for a job. The important bit in an application is the experience that comes from working in a "work like environment" (lets say a soup kitchen) even if there was no payment. Knitting hats is a very nice thing to do, but unless the workplace is a tailor specialized in hats, I don't think it's what is meant when people talk about "volunteering" in context of the workplace.

Comment: @SolarMike It's the semantic difference between donate goods and volunteer time.  The cake could have been artisianally made from scratch or it could have been bought from the local supermarket. The School Gala doesn't know the difference (and doesn't care).  OTOH Demon can't volunteer his time by proxy in the same manner as simply buying a cake.  (However it is a grey area if Demon said he "donated his time")

Comment: @SolarMike - I'm not sure if you missed the 'and that's a good thing' line - it's not 'I don't respect the time' - it's about physically going somewhere else *and being directed to work*

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume without context that you intend to list this on your resume, or on a job application in the "previous work" section. You **can**, of course -- nobody can stop you -- but it might not help you if you do and could even hurt you.

In order to be helpful, an entry on your resume has to help me connect with what I want to hire you to do. So if I want to hire you to make hats, or to just let your hair grow, then a simple entry like "hat maker" or "hair grower" will work. But I doubt anyone plans to hire you for that. That's fine: I've hired software developers who don't have software development jobs on their resumes. The key is to make sure the job connects to what you're applying for.

For most jobs, whether that's dog walking, lawn mowing, babysitting, fast food, whatever, there's a sort of implied contract. I can assume you mostly showed up on time, did what you were supposed to do, didn't break any huge social norms, that sort of thing. This doesn't apply to your two pieces of "experience" -- you made the hats when you felt like it and I am guessing, worked alone at home  making whatever hats you wanted to, then took them somewhere when they were done. Certainly for the hair growing there is no information to be learned about your punctuality, ability to follow procedures, understanding of employment norms and so on just because you have done that.

(And here's where the hurt can come in -- if you don't make it clear this is volunteer work, and I discover that because I recognize the program you mention, or I ask you in an interview, then I may file you under "liar" or at least "deceiver" for pretending it was a real job. And you may not be able to recover from that.)

Now perhaps you can spin me a tale about how the hat thing was actually assigned ("please make 10 hats by Dec 1st") and you had to follow patterns other people chose, deliver on deadline, and so on. If so, then you could cautiously include it in your experience section -- but be clear both how it relates to the more typical work for which you're applying, and that it was not something you were hired to do.

Probably a better plan is to have a "hobbies and interests" section where you can describe both of these and generally what a generous and nice person you are.